# Using expect to execute remote script and get script exit status

Tags: linux, shell-script, shell, expect

I have a script which is on remote server which returns exit status of the script. Now I want to execute that remote script using expect and get the exit status of the script.

My remote server script

```
 #!/usr/bin/ksh
 echo "Test script"
 exit 1
```

My expect script on local server

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh
expect -c "
log_user 0
spawn ssh abc@abc /var/tmp/test.ksh
expect { password:test }
log_user 1
expect 100%
"
```

Output of the expect script

```
Test script
```

But I also want the exit status of my remote script i.e 1.
How can i achieve this using expect.

Answer (score 1):

Some `wait(2)` system call (maybe instead `waitpid` or `wait4`; these may or may not be the same manual page depending on the flavor of unix) obtains the exit status word. In `expect` this is exposed via the `wait` procedure documented in the `expect(1)` man page. For example a process can be written that exits with a psuedo-random exit code, and that value obtained from the return value of `wait`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env expect

spawn -noecho \
  expect -c {set code [expr { int(100*rand()) }]; puts "hi $code"; exit $code}
expect -ex "hi"
expect eof

set exunt [wait -i -1]
puts $exunt

set child_exit_code [lindex $exunt end]
puts $child_exit_code
```

This when run should produce something like

```
$ expect ./expectexitcode 
hi 78
700 ðӶ 0 78
78
$
```